# Subject-verb agreement in questions that start with wh- words

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement

I have a sentence that says "Simon and Shirli are friends"
When I want to ask about the subject, how should I ask:

Who are friends?

or

Who is friends?

Thanks!!

Comment: I realize the suggested duplicate question talks about just a singular subject, but in the answers, the case where there are two friends is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Since *friends* is a plural form, you also need a plural subject here. It is not possible for one single person to be *friends*. **One person** can be *a friend*, but for *friends* there is **more than one person** involved.

*Friends*  needs to correspond with a plural subject here. This is what we call **concord**, grammatical agreement between two words in a sentence:

> - **They** are **friends**.
> - **He** is **a friend**.

Note that the verb also corresponds to the subject, that is also concord. You can't say *he are* or *they is*.

---

So if you are asking about *Simon and Shirli*, you should say:

> Who **are** friends?

Possible answer:

> Simon and Shirli are.

---

If you are asking about only one person, you should say:

> Who **is** *his/her/their friend*?

Possible answers:

> - She is.
> - Shirli is.
> - Simon is.
> - Jack is.

Answer (score 0):

With *wh-* words, if they refer to a plural noun, then you use a plural verb.

So it would be "Who are friends?".